# Flutter ListView refuses to scroll

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I'm building a Flutter app that will play my YouTube playlists. The player takes up fixed real estate at the top of the screen, and my playlist populates the bottom of the screen in a scrollable list, like so:

[image]

The problem is, no matter what I try, I cannot get the ListView to scroll. It's extremely frustrating as I have definitely made scrollable ListViews before. Here is my code:

```
      body: SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 8 * hRatio,
            ),
            // Video player begins here
            BlocBuilder<ChannelPlayerBloc, ChannelPlayerState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is ChannelPlayerInitialState) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: size.width - 40,
                      height: (size.width - 40) / 1.78,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: const [
                            Text('Click a video'),
                            Text('to play...'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (state is ChannelPlayerLoadingState) {
                  return Center(
                    child: Container(
                      width: size.width - 40,
                      height: (size.width - 40) / 1.78,
                      color: Colors.black38,
                      child: const Center(
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(40.0),
                          child: LoadingIndicator(
                            indicatorType: Indicator.ballTrianglePathColoredFilled,
                            colors: [
                              Colors.redAccent,
                              Colors.greenAccent,
                              Colors.blue,
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (state is ChannelPlayerLoadedState) {
                  return PodVideoPlayer(controller: state.controller);
                }
                return Container();
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10 * hRatio,
            ),
            // Scrollable playlist begins here
            BlocBuilder<YtChannelBloc, YtChannelState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is YtInitialState) {
                  return const SizedBox(
                    height: double.infinity,
                    child: Center(
                      child: SizedBox(height: 35, width: 35, child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                if (state is YtLoadedState) {
                  return Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        for (YtVideoModel video in state.channel)
                          Card(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                context.read<ChannelPlayerBloc>().add(ChannelPlayerLoad(video.videoId));
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(width: 8 * wRatio),
                                  Image.network(
                                    video.thumbnail,
                                    width: size.width * .25,
                                    height: size.width * .25 / 1.78,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                                      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0 * hRatio),
                                    width: size.width * .60,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Title: ${video.title}',
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                        Text('Published: ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(video.publishedAt)}'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Container();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Use sliverList instead it will work

Comment: @RidhaRezzag thank you! You'll never believe this, but the problem was simply that I didn't know how to use the Android Emulator. I was two-finger dragging, expecting it to scroll, and I needed to click and drag for it to work. Doh!!! I feel so foolish. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm so embarrassed. Turns out I just didn't know how to use the Android Emulator properly. The code was working correctly the whole time.

Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

Try Adding SingleChildScrollView before listview.

```
Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(child: ListView(
                      children: [
                        for (YtVideoModel video in state.channel)
                          Card(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            child: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                context.read<ChannelPlayerBloc>().add(ChannelPlayerLoad(video.videoId));
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  SizedBox(width: 8 * wRatio),
                                  Image.network(
                                    video.thumbnail,
                                    width: size.width * .25,
                                    height: size.width * .25 / 1.78,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    loadingBuilder: (context, child, loadingProgress) {
                                      if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0 * hRatio),
                                    width: size.width * .60,
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: [
                                        Text(
                                          'Title: ${video.title}',
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                        ),
                                        Text('Published: ${DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(video.publishedAt)}'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ));
```

Comment: when I do that it throws an exception:
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.

I've tried wrapping in a Container, to constrain height, but it still won't scroll.

Comment: ListView is scrollable by default. You don't need to add a SingleChildScrollView to make it scrollable.